# How to create an open (unencrypted) AdHoc WiFi network in Windows8?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, ad-hoc-network

I've read thousands of tutorials but the command:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=try key=12345678
```

Creates a secure network only. How can I create an open unencrypted AdHoc wireless network in Windows 8?

Comment: It looks to me like you need to add authentication=open-none but the PC I'm at right now doesn't have wlan so I can't check, sorry. See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755301(v=WS.10).aspx#bkmk_wlanSetProfileparameter

Comment: Try also removing the key option.  You don't want a key for an unencrypted network.

Comment: Check out redmondpie's answer [here](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-set-up-wireless-ad-hoc-internet-connection-in-windows-8/).

Answer (score 2):

I take from the help text that this is impossible using netsh. The full text is reproduced below:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan set hostednetwork ?

Usage: set hostednetwork [mode=]allow|disallow [ssid=]<ssid>
                         [key=]<passphrase> [keyUsage=]persistent|temporary

Parameters:

    Tag             Value
    mode            Specifies whether to allow or disallow the hosted network.
    ssid            SSID of the hosted network.
    key             The user security key used by the hosted network.
    keyUsage        Specifies whether the user security key is persistent or
                    temporary.

Remarks:

    This command changes the properties of hosted network, including: SSID
    of the hosted network, allow or disallow the hosted network in the system,
    and a user security key that is used by the hosted network.


    The user security key should be a string with 8 to 63 ASCII characters,
    eg. a passphrase, or 64 hexadecimal digits which represent 32 binary
    bytes.


    If keyUsage is specified as persistent, the security key will be saved
    and used when the hosted network is started again in future. Otherwise
    it will be used only when the current or next time the hosted network
    is started. Once the hosted network is stopped, the temporary security
    key will be deleted from the system. If keyUsage is not specified, it
    is persistent by default.

    This command requires administrator privileges to allow or disallow the
    hosted network.

Examples:

    set hostednetwork mode=allow
    set hostednetwork ssid=ssid1
    set hostednetwork key=passphrase keyUsage=persistent
```